# Tcl interact after sourcing a file.tcl

Tags: tcl, expect, readline

I want to interact after sourcing a file in Tcl prompt.
i.e.,

]$ tclsh myCode.tcl

// execute my code

% // Enters Interact mode within myCode.tcl

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290982/tcl-expect-interact-command-echos-previous-output-from-spawned-rlwrap-process/19379047#19379047) - this is a duplicate.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn What on earth are you talking about? That one was about interacting with a subordinate process whereas this is about interacting with the current interpreter.

Comment: The problem is the same: "How can I execute some stuff in an interp and give the user the interactive shell?". The [tag:expect] tag does not help to convince me otherwise. ([XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378))

Comment: “Current interp”/“subordinate process” is a key distinguishing factor, and leads to very different solutions. (The [tag:readline] tag points to this being a local-process problem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way of doing this is to use the [`commandloop`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1968) command from the [TclX extension](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tclx).

```
package require Tclx

#... define things and run things...

# Let the user issue commands
commandloop
```

The wiki page linked above discusses how to do this without using TclX.

Comment: That works, but commands have to be entered with their full name; using just the first part of the command name doesn't work (as in tclsh), why is that?

Comment: Is there a way to get editing capabilities like in `rlfe tclsh` with this method?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I may be reading too little into this, or over-simplifying it, but... isn't what you need the `interact` command?

If you want Tcl/Expect to do something, then yield control back to the user, pls check out the interact command in the man page link below:

http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html

Comment: interact throws an error saying:  cannot interact with self - set spawn_id to spawned process

Comment: Hmm... so I guess you're not spawning another process and using Expect, then? If so, then the interact command will be of no use.
Sorry, I asumed you were using Expect with your Tcl.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd rather do it in pure tcl without any external packages, the simplest implementation of a tclsh prompt is very simple indeed. Just put this at the end of `myCode.tcl`:

```
fileevent stdin readable {
    puts [eval [gets stdin]]
}

vwait forever
```

You can even implement this as a standalone program that sources your other tcl scripts.

Of course, the example code above is so simple it doesn't even print a prompt or handle things like multiline commands but it's a good starting point for you to modify and customize.

Comment: I like this. I changed it a bit to give it the feel of the actual shell `puts -nonewline "[eval [gets stdin]] [eval [puts -nonewline "\n% "]]";`

Answer (score 0):

You may try `tkcon`, an interactive tclsh which creates a separate window. I wrote a small shell script `mytclsh` with the first line

```
#!/usr/bin/tkcon myscript.tcl
```

and made it executable (`chmod 755 mytclsh`). This executes `myscript.tcl` and then goes interactive. Here's more information on `tkcon`: https://wuhrr.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/a-solution-for-tclsh-editing-woes/